# Lazy loading and dynamic object in Play Framework

Tags: java, jquery, playframework, lazy-loading

I'm new for this play framework. I use Java for development. So, I want to ask some questions for the expert. Great thanks for the solution!

1. Can we do lazy loading the images like in jQuery do? I've researched that we can use ebean, but I don't know where to start.
2. How we can do a dynamic label(or object properties)? In @message, we can call the static String, but this shown same label for the first and second @message. So, how if I want to make each of inputtext have label "name" and "password" separately?

   ```
   <form action="@routes.Application.addBar()" method="post">
       @message
       <input name="name" placeholder="Username">
       <br>
       @message
       <input name="password" placeholder="Password" >
       <input type="submit" value="Login">
   </form>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer,

1. The play compile this scala template at server side and send it to browser, you can do lazy load of the image by any client side technology like jquery or any other framework.

Ebean comes by default in playframework 2.x, you can start Ebean by the following link

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaEbean

2. It better to use Play form validation in such case. please refer the following link.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms